# Timestamp not working with strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have tried to search it up, but it seems I can't find the correct answer.
Currently I am uploading the current time from one of my scripts after a first email is being send to companies, so after it has been send it will upload `now()` to one of my tables in MySQL. This is uploading `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Another script will resend a different email after five days with the partial script

```
if( $company_timestamp < strtotime('-5 days') && $email_sent == "NO" ){ /* Code */}
```

Where `$company_timestamp` is the date and time told before.

It is indeed sending the email, but it seems it is not getting the correct time, because it is sending this email even after 5 seconds.
Is the format wrong of the date and time? And how can I make `strotime()` work with my `now()` in the database.

Comment: an example of what does the variable `$company_timestamp` contain

Comment: I just send myself an email and it contains: 2016-11-24 17:33:57

Comment: try converting both of the times to unix times and then compare them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define how strototime() should act. In your case you would have to define it this way:
`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 days'));` as your variable $company_timestamp returns YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss. Another option would be to transform your variable to "strtotime" date. So: strtotime($company_timestamp).

So your code would be in the first case:

```
if( $company_timestamp < date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 days')) && $email_sent == "NO" ){
```

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$company_timestamp` is a string, you need to convert it before you can compare it.

```
<?php
$email_sent = "NO";
$company_timestamp = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

if( strtotime( $company_timestamp ) < date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-5 days' ) ) && $email_sent == "NO" )
{
  echo "Yes";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `$company_timestamp` is a string. Look my solution. That works and `$company_timestamp` is still a string. Remember that PHP is loosely typed.